# Jquery will not remove div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have form in which I am adding some dynamic actions.  I have a table in which I have rows of positions 
applicants applied for.  There is an offer postion button and when they click on the offer button I want to insert the offer fields to be submitted and updated.  I can get the feilds to insert but when I click on the cancel transaction button, I can't get it to empty the div addapptrans where the form is built.  Below is the code. I know it must be something simple I am missing.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
        $(".offerposition").click(function(){
            var row = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:nth-child(1)').text();

            alert('You clicked on ' +row);
            $("#addapptrans").empty();
            $("#addapptrans").append(
                $("<input>").attr('type','hidden').attr( 'value',row).attr('Name','Mchposid'))
            .append(
                $("<input>").attr('type','submit').attr( 'value','Complete Offer').attr('id','completeoffertrx').attr('name','completeoffertrx').addClass("buttonlarge buttonmargin")
            ).append(
                $("<input>").attr('type','button').attr( 'value','Cancel Transaction').attr('id','canceloffertrx').attr('name','canceloffertrx').addClass("buttonlarge buttonmargin")
            );

        }
        )
    }
    );

    $(function(){
        $("#canceloffertrx").click(function(){
         $("#addapptrans").empty();   

        })  
    })
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form >

    <div id="addapptrans"></div>
    <p class="posttitle">Positions applied For</p>
    <table class="tabpositions">

        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="position">Position</th>
            <th class="department">Department</th>
            <th class="dateapp">Date Applied</th>
            <th class="appdate">Offer?</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td style="display: none;">2281</td>
            <td>Building Service Worker - Part time</td>
            <td>Environmental Services</td>
            <td>08/13/2001</td>
            <td><input type="button" class="offerposition" value="Offer Position"></td> 
        </tr>                
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>
```

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here:

```
$(function(){
    $("#canceloffertrx").click(function(){
        $("#addapptrans").empty();
    })  
})
```

Runs before `#canceloffertrx` exists on the page. So `$("#canceloffertrx").click(fn)` Matches zero elements on the page, and binds a click handler to all zero of them.

---

You can fix this by binding the click handler to the document, or closest parent that is present, instead.

```
$('#addapptrans').on('click', '#canceloffertrx', function(){
```

This says that when the element `#addapptrans` receives a click event, and element that matches the selector `#canceloffertrx` was the one that was actually clicked, fire the event handler function.

Or by binding the click handler when you create the button.

```
$("<input>")
  .attr('type','submit')
  .attr( 'value','Complete Offer')
  .attr('id','completeoffertrx')
  .attr('name','completeoffertrx')
  .addClass("buttonlarge buttonmargin")
  .click(function() { ... });
```

---

Lastly, some style advice :) Especially when chaining jQuery methods, you can put each call on it's own line which makes it much more readable.

And you should also know that `attr()` can accept an object as an argument, allowing to call it just once to set many attributes.

```
$("<input>")
  .attr({
    type:  'submit',
    value: 'Complete Offer',
    id:    'completeoffertrx',
    name:  'completeoffertrx'
  })
  .addClass("buttonlarge buttonmargin")
  .click(function() { ... });
```

Comment: It is best to attach delegated event handlers to the nearest non-changing ancestor element (e.g. `#addapptrans` in this question). `document` is the fallback if nothing is closer.